# Find occurrences of subsequence in a binary string (non-necessarily-contiguous)

Tags: string, algorithm, search, time-complexity, subsequence

Given a binary string with 0 and 1. I want to know number of occurrences of subsequences `01` and `10` in the given input String. Subsequences are not necessarily contiguous.

For example:

```
input : "10101"
"01" subsequences: 3, with indices (1,2), (1,4), (3,4)
"10" subsequences: 3, with indices (0,1), (0,3), (2,3)

Result = 3 + 3 = 6
```

My idea is to use nested loops to find the occurrence of 01 in input string, and do again with another nested loops to get for 10

Here is my code:

```
public static int solve(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    // count occurrences of "01" in s
    int count1 = 0;
    int index = s.indexOf('0');
    if(index != -1) {
        for(int i=index; i<n; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(c != '0') continue;
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                char d = s.charAt(j);
                if(d == '1')  count1++;
            }
        }
    }
    // count occurrences of "10" in s
    int count2 = 0;
    index = s.indexOf('1');
    if(index != -1) {
        for(int i=index; i<n; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(c != '1') continue;
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                char d = s.charAt(j);
                if(d == '0')  count2++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count1 + count2; 
}
```

How to do this in optimal way by reducing time complexity.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.  An O(n) solution does not require nested loops.

Comment: What about (0,3)?

Comment: @stark, I corrected it now

Comment: I guess you could list the indices of all ones, list the indices of all zeroes, then build the Cartesian product of all pairs (index of one, index of zero) then partition this Cartesian product into two lists (pairs with one before zero) and (pairs with zero before one). Technically the complexity is proportional to the length of the output, but I'm not sure it's going to be much faster than the simple nested for-loops you were thinking about.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I added my code now

Comment: Wait, you only want to count the subsequences? Not list them?

Comment: @Stef, yes I need only count

Comment: Then rentox's answer below works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting the first solution that comes to mind, it's very simple and clean, I don't take into account 2 different counters but with a small modification you can do it. This example strictly applies to your case, if you wanted to change the binary strings to be checked, this solution would no longer be suitable.

```
    String word = "10101";
    int result = 0, count0 = 0, count1 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == '0') {
            count0++;
            result += count1;
        }
        else {
            count1++;
            result += count0;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Count: " + result);
```

Comment: Can you provide explanation of the solution and how it solves the problem.

Comment: So, for the explanation I limit myself to analyzing only the count of "01", for "10" it is the same;
for the calculation it is fine to use a counter of the occurrences of "1" found up to that moment, in fact when I find a "0" then that "0" will be part of as many "10"s as the value in the counter at that instant since the sequences may not be consecutive;

Comment: examples:
 "10" -> when it finds "0" the "1" counter is 1
| "110" -> when it finds "0" the counter of "1" is 2
| "1010" -> when it finds the first "0" the counter is 1, when it finds the second the counter is 2, in fact the correct result added is 3.
Tell me if I was clear.